# Golang type assertion

Tags: go

I have created a type Role based off string, and I am now trying to get it to work with the database driver by implementing the Valuer and Scanner interfaces

```
type Role string

func (r *Role) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    r = (*Role)(value.(string))

    return nil
}

func (r *Role) Value(value driver.Value, err error) {
    if err != nil {
        value = string(r)
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error:

```
The Go code app/entities/user.go does not compile: cannot convert value.(string) (type string) to type *Role
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is working code for the first function:

```
func (r *Role) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    *r = Role(value.(string))
    return nil
}
```

Although you may wish to use `s, ok := value.(string)` and return an error for `!ok` instead of panic-ing.

The signature for the a `driver.Valuer` is not what you gave but:

```
func (r Role) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return string(r), nil
}
```

Note this doesn't handle or produce NULL values.

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/XgcYiSHv4b)

Comment: Aha, it was the pointer dereference that was catching me out.

Comment: Solution for the second one is ```func (r *Role) Value(value driver.Value, err error) {
 if err != nil {
  value = string(*r)
 }
}```

Comment: That's interesting. I never saw Go code where the method receiver was modified and wouln't have considered doing this. I also was sure converting from an interface to a concrete type needs a type assertion.

Comment: There is a type assertion, ```value.(string)```

Comment: I see, just ignoring the second return value.

Comment: For a string type you don't need to use a pointer receiver for `Value`, and isn't it `func (r Role) Value() (driver.Value, error)`? You might want to use the two valued version of the type assert and return an error instead of panic-ing if `Scan` is called with a type other than `string`.

Comment: You could also reference the implementation of [`sql.NullString`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString) (follow the linked documentation through to the source).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's a good idea to modify the receiver of your method (r) in the Scan method.

You need a type assertion to convert `value interface{}` to string.
You are trying to convert a `string` to a `pointer to Role`.

```
func (r *Role) Scan(value interface{}) (retVal Role, err error) {
    var s string;

    if v,ok := value.(string); ok {
      s = v;
    }
    var rx Role
    rx = Role(s)

    var rx2 *Role
    rx2 = &rx
    _ = rx // just to silence the compiler for this demonstration
    _ = rx2 // just to silence the compiler for this demonstration
    return rx, nil
}
```

should work

Comment: If we are not modifying the receiver or returning a value how does the driver no what to do?

Comment: The receiver r `is` like the `this` in objects. You can return more than one value (value and error) in Go. I don't now what requirements you have for your Scan method.

Comment: Yes, but the job of scan is to convert the string sent back from the database to a role, this is being assigned to rx, but not to r and not being returned only the local variable gets the result. I am missing something.

Comment: The Scanner interface defines scan as ```Scan(src interface{}) error``` you are returning multiple results

Comment: Then you can't return anything else than an error. Can you provide a link to the API docs of your Scanner interface so I can look up what it is about?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Can you elaborate on why modifying `r` in-place is not a good idea?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, you mean [`sql.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner)? Just like [`json.Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) and others, this modifies the receiver. (And just like `fmt.Scanf` family of functions modify pointer arguments).